# Gear reduction vs PWM duty cycle limiting

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, efficiency

I am wondering about adjusting the output RPMs of wheels in vehicle. Lets assume two situations, in which we are using BLDC motor with ESC, where the PWM is our controlling signal.

1. We have got gear reduction, that reduces motor RPMs to wheel RPMs that causes required maximum velocity for maximum possible PWM duty cycle.
2. We do not reduce motor RPMs too much, instead we limit our PWM duty cycle to value, that causes required velocity.

What are the pros and cons of that variants? What should I apply? (In first situation there may be a problem with too much gear reduction required - hard to apply it in the mechanical meaning).

Comment: Gear reduction increases the torque available - reducing the speed by changing the PWM duty cycle does not.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd want to choose a gear reduction so that max desired velocity = max motor velocity.  That way you're best utilizing the torque and operational range of the PWM.